# Como hacer que un bot mande mensaje automaticamente con discordjs nodejs y phantomjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, phantomjs

Tengo un bot que hace scrapping y cuando encuentra una coincidencia entre unas palabras claves y una lista que me arroja el scrapping me debería lanzar un mensaje automáticamente al discord, lo que ocurre es que para que ese mensaje ocurra alguien debe estar hablando en el servidor de discord, quisiera saber como hacer para que esto pase sin que nadie este hablando.

Mi código:

```
var keyword = ['Cosmetics / Skin Care - Classification Validation - Feature Mini Group 2', 'Morphological Annotation', 'French News: Is This Person Involved In A Crime Or Sanctioned?', 'Label Roads( With Sidewalks) In Images'];
    for(let i=0; i<JobsListing.length; i++){
    for(let j=0; j<keyword.length; j++){
        if(JobsListing[i][1] === keyword[j]){          
            client.on('message', (message)=>{
              if(message.author.bot === false) {
                // Do something if message doesn't come from a bot.
                message.channel.send(`${JobsListing[i][0]} ${JobsListing[i][1]} Paga ${JobsListing[i][3]} (Ysense) Tareas: ${JobsListing[i][5]}`);
              }

            });
        }
    }
   }
```

En suposición debería mandarse el mensaje cuando se encuentra alguna coincidencia pero no es así, para que funcione tiene que haber alguien escribiendo en el chat